# Scala Spark MLLib NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

I am learning ALS in Spark mllib
bu when i try to create Rating to passing to ALS.train I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/Rating
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I use 
sbt 0.13.15, 
Scala 2.10.4, 
spark-core 2.10, 
spark-mllib 2.10, 
tried on both java 7 and 8

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Try to import it frm another package import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating

Comment: the result still the same, NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: What version of spark dependencies do you have ? What you have shared is just the scala version of those Spark dependencies ?

Comment: @eliasah  `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-core_2.10"     % "2.1.0" ,
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10"    % "2.1.0"     % "provided"
)`

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for my case

the thing is i try to run this spark with IntelliJ IDE and I found that in my Build.sbt i have something like this to use dependencies

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.0" , "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "provided" )`

the problem is at `"provided"` i should change this to `"compile"` when i try to run with IntelliJ otherwise i'll see error like that

Comment: The one I have copied from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11/2.3.1 is "runtime", changing it to "provided" works

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just remove the provided will solve the problem

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.0" ,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0" )
```